# jquery.on() equivalent for prototypeJS

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

What is the equivalent to

```
jQuery.on('change','select',function(){});
```

for prototypeJS?

Comment: http://prototypejs.org/learn/event-delegation

Comment: just a search for [prototype js events dynamic elements](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=prototype+js+events+dynamic+elements&spell=1) gave us the answer!!!